Dumping all import symbols from x64dbg
I want to export the symbol addresses from all loaded modules in x64dbg. I know I can do this DLL-by-DLL from the Symbols tab (click on one module > right click in table > Copy > Export Table), but I want to do all of them at once. It doesn't matter if they're exported it one big file, or one file per module.
I can't find any command that does this. Have I missed one? labellist only shows labels I've defined myself.
I tried exporting the database, which is easily parseable JSON, but I don't see labels from system DLLs there, only labels in the main EXE module. This seemed promising but is missing the key info I want.
